# Akka.Net mixing async/await and PipeTo

Tags: async-await, akka.net

I understand that in general, async/await in Akka.net actors block the actor's mailbox. In one `ReceiveAsync` handler, I'd like to have a blocking async/await section followed by a PipeTo that does *not* block. I am wondering if the following will accomplish that:

```
class MyActor : ReceiveActor
{

   public MyActor()
   {
      ReceiveAsync<MyMsg>(Handle);
   }

   private async Task Handle(MyMsg msg)
   {
      if (_someNotTrivialCondition)
      {
         // Run this on actor thread; blocking WANTED here.
         // (Ie, I don't want DoSomeWorkAsync to begin until
         // this await statement completes.)
         await RunSomeNonTrivialCompensationLogic();
      }
      
      // Now an API call; blocking NOT WANTED here; just
      // send the data back to the sender.
      DoSomeWorkAsync().PipeTo(Context.Sender, Self,
          success: result => new MyResponse(result)),
          failure: ex => new MyResponse(ex));
   }
}
```

I have an inkling that maybe there's something about Tasks created in a `ReceiveAsync` that might cause this to *not* do what I'm expecting.

Is mixing async/await and `PipeTo` in the same `ReceiveAsync` going to work as the code comments describe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a complete expert on Akka, but I'm using it on regular basis.

It is not completely clear from your question if you try to run the await and the pipeto concurrently or not. So I try to take both scenarios into consideration.

First of all, I try to avoid async/await in my actors if I can. If I can't, I try to isolate the steps in different actors, with a head/supervising actor containing the logic and possibly changing the behavior (become/unbecome) of the actor depending on some values (like in your case the '_someNotTrivialCondition' condition). (You can find more on this in the akka.net documentation. The finite state machine is a nice example.)

The separate steps are in 'child' actors and of course I need to await for the task to be completed, but that should be done in an isolated way (in this separate child actor) and when that isolated task is finished, it 'tells' the supervising actor that it has done and gives the result for example in a message. The supervising actor will react on that message and like stated before, it is easy to change the behavior of the actor and act different.

In short, I try to achieve more of a reactive (event/message driven) sort of computing (with tell) than 'awaiting' or 'asking'.

However, purely on topic of your question, if we look at you example, lets combine the rules for an async/await and a PipeTo statement in akka.net.

An await will block the actors messagebox, so no processing of this actor will be done until the await is reached. After that, it is open for other things and messages can be processed again.
Also, it is still .net/c#, so it will not execute the code following the await unless the await is no longer in place. After all, THAT is the whole purpose of the await statement ! So, no, it will not execute the pipeto code concurrently if that is your intent. If it is your intention, you should drop the await keyword and that should execute both concurrently and in my opinion should work fine.

A PipeTo will send a message if the task is done, like you defined in your example. Again, if the await line of code needs to be executed (the condition is true), the pipeto will not be executed until that await is no longer blocking the code (c#/.net default code execution).

So, unless your 'Context.Sender' is 'Self', it should send 'success' or 'failure' to this 'Sender-actor' and unless that actor is blocked somehow, it should work fine, if it is not the intention to do them concurrently.

Comment: Appreciate your thoughtful response. I don't agree about the avoiding of async/await in actors. I explained my point of view in detail to Aaron Stannard here (https://petabridge.com/blog/top-7-akkadotnet-stumbling-blocks/#comment-2246218006) and got a generally favorable response from him (and others). I'll clarify my question a bit by editing it. My take-away from your answer is that, as far as you know, it *should* work the way I'm expecting. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I think it is more of a personal flavor and yes, I do use async/await sometimes but I try to avoid creating 'tasks' myself (if I'm using akka). It is hard to find people knowing akka well and using both concepts doesn't make code better understandable. I try to avoid deadlocks and to be honest, using async/await extensively is a challenge (to avoid all sorts of woobly woobly magic happening). Personally, if I would be so into async/await, I would look deeper into a micro-threading solution like the one used in the open source Stride game engine and leave akka aside.

Comment: Reading your example code with the extra info, I see no reason why it shouldn't work as expected. I noticed you are not a novice to akka nor to async/await, so why don't you test it out and discover for yourself ? See no reason why this would be hard to make a test case.

Comment: Thanks again. Couple responses: "using async/await extensively is a challenge" - I find the opposite: async/await tends to make the process direct & easy to read, while PipeTo + child actors are less direct (the code gets more plumbing vs business logic). But which I will use is almost always determined by the desired behavior: async/await to leverage the actor's one-at-a-time guarantee in a particular sequence of steps, PipeTo for throughput. Re: "test it out and discover for yourself" I'll give that a shot; sometimes mixing sync and async code blocks in c# has subtle and unexpected problems.

Comment: I agree that if one wishes to do 'sequential steps', await can make it simple and readable (but akka too with behavior change). But I don't get why you would use akka then ? Await blocks and akka is designed not to block ('ask' is by nobody serious advized) and allows massive parallel execution of code/actors. Massive ! If I await everything, that will limit my system dramatically. So only for moderate systems with more than enough capacity I would advice what you suggest. In all other cases I would suggest reactive programming or akka used in reactive way (tell and not ask).

Comment: Geertie, it depends on the actor. Some actors ought to be massively parallel with PipeTo to make sure they don't block while waiting for IO. This actor might spin off a child actor that performs sequential steps on a single entity; async/await makes this actor's code much simpler. A concrete example: an actor that manages a chat system should be massively parallel, but an instance of a chat bot participating in a one-on-one conversation within that system can be written simpler since it doesn't need parallelism, but still leverages the one-msg-at-a-time behavior. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: If your chat bot is very simple with no 'intelligence' at all, just replying with simple answers, I agree. Don't see the reason to use akka in that case anyway (asp.net will be fine). However, if my bot needs to do word, sentence and context analysis (lot of parallel) and verify the interpreted with reality and afterwards formulate a 'good' answer (again parallel if it needs to be acceptable), it will be less efficient with async/await. Take my word, this is my line of work. Right tool for the right job and if you need too much of async/await (excepts for IO) in akka, you shouldn't use akka.

Comment: You said "excepts for IO" - please elaborate; isn't that 99% of where async/await is used? And does that imply you *do* use a/a in your actors, but pretty much just for io?

Comment: You can write any function as a task, so no, it is not only IO 99% of where a/a is used. I know large scale websites running perfectly on only a/a (no akka). In akka, it should be 99,99% of the a/a usage. That is my point the whole time. And yes, it is virtually impossible NOT to use async/await in any (large scale) akka application. And yes, if I for instance would need Roslyn to run several scrips simultanious in an akka app, I will use the runasync() method (not IO thus) because I have no other option. You try to avoid blocking (a/a) since that is so NOT akka, even if it reads easier ...

Comment: In informatics there is a universal wisdom and that is that if what you do solves the problem and is acceptable for all parties involved, it is a good solution. So, if what you are currently doing works for you, you should continue doing it. If you have some performance issues, I hope you will give the 'avoid async/await in akka' a second thought. To summarize what I try to do : If possible avoid a/a, if not possible try to use pipeto, if not possible/desirable use await.

Comment: If I'm reading your last comments correctly, I think we agree. The 1st time I had this conversation I was trying to follow the "avoid async/await" advice, and I'm looking at SQL access code: connection.OpenAsync(), command.ExecuteDataReaderAsync(), dataReader.ReadAsync(), and I'm thinking, "This code gets pretty opaque, with lots of new, strange race conditions, if I use PipeTo on all these Asyncs... and I don't want to handle any messages in this particular actor in between row reads anyway... is PipeTo really the way to go here?" I'm open to learning, but I still believe the answer is No.

Comment: If you only have one sql connection at a time, it is fine what you are doing. Your app will not be bottlenecked by the blocking . If your system is under stress (whatever reason), blocking is not the way to go. 'Pipeto' + 'behavior changes' equals your 'await' EXCEPT for the blocking. All you need is 'state'. Look at the way TCP is handled internally by akka to have an example. Good to hear you are always open to learning and hope you will remember this if you have performance issues with one of your (akka) apps. Cheers.

Comment: In case anyone comes here later and wants Aaron Stannard's opinion on async/await vs. PipeTo, check out this article he just wrote, which precisely addresses the debate I had here in the comments with Geertie. https://petabridge.com/blog/async-await-vs-pipeto